# Saml2 spring-security single logout

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-saml2

It looks like the existing spring-security Saml2 configuration does not have the single logout functionality according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#saml2. I already have the logout url for openAM (ForgeRock), but what's the best way to handling logout using spring-security for Saml2?